# How to create an Electron app that is also served from local server

Tags: electron

I want to create an Electron application that allows the same wrapped website (albeit through different url-routes) to be accessible through a local webserver. So when the application starts, a local webserver is started that serves the exact same site.

How would i set this up?

Comment: If you would have searched online instead, It's available [Here](https://fabiofranchino.com/blog/use-electron-as-local-webserver/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it.

In the main.js, you start the server and then open a BrowserWindow with that URL.

Something like,

```
require('child_process).execSync('node server.js');
mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');
```

Using child_process module to start the server.